# Double authentication for RESTful API

Tags: ruby, api, restful-authentication

I'm currently building a RESTful API to our web service, which will be accessed by 3rd party web and mobile apps. We want to have certain level of control over API consumers (i.e. those web and mobile apps), so we can do API requests throttling and/or block certain malicious clients. For that purpose we want every developer who will be accessing our API to obtain an API key from us and use it to access our API endpoints. For some API calls that are not dealing with the specific user information, that's the only required level of authentication & authorization, which I call "app"-level A&A. However, some API calls deal with information belonging to the specific users, so we need a way to allow those users to login and authorize the app to access their data, which creates a second level (or "user"-level A&A).

It makes a lot of sense to use OAuth2 for the "user"-level A&A and I think I have a pretty good understanding of what I need to do here.

I also implemented OAuth1-like scheme, where app developers receive a pair of API key & secret, supply their API key with every call and use secret to sign their requests (again, it's very OAuth1 like and I should probably just use OAuth1 for that).

Now the problem that I have is how to marry those two different mechanisms. My current hypothesis is that I continue to use API key/secret pair to sign all requests to be able to access all API endpoints and for those calls that require access to user-specific information apps will need to go through OAuth2 flow and obtain access tokens and supply them.

So, my question to the community is - does it sounds like a good solution or there are some better ways to architect this.

I'd also appreciate any links to existing solutions that I could use, instead of re-inventing the wheel (our services is Ruby/Rails-based).

Answer (score 0):

Your key/secret pair isn't really giving you any confidence in the authorship of mobile apps.  The secret will be embedded in the executable, then given to users, and there's really nothing you can do to prevent the user from extracting the key.

In the Stack Exchange API, we just use OAuth 2.0 and accept that all we can do is cutoff abusive users (or IPs, in earlier revisions without OAuth).  We do provide keys for tracking purposes, but they're not secret (and grant nothing of value, so there's no incentive to steal them).

In terms of preventing abuse, what we do is throttle based on IP in the absence of an auth token, but switch to a per-user throttle when there is one.

When dealing with purely malicious clients, we unleash the lawyers (malicious in our case is almost always violation of cc-wiki guidelines); technical solutions aren't sophisticated enough in our estimation.  Note that the incidence of malicious clients is really really low (single digits in years of operation, with millions of daily API requests).

In short, I'd ditch OAuth 1.0 and switch your throttles to a hybrid of IP and user based.